# knockout binding issue

Tags: knockout.js, viewmodel

I use mapping plugin for creating the view model. Here's the watcher output from Chrome:

```
viewModel: Object
 Id: function observable() 
 Language: function observable() 
 QuoteListViewModel: Object
 QuoteSelectedViewModel: Object
```

The MVC Model is :

```
public class QuoteRequestViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public LanguageEnum Language { get; set; }   

    public QuoteViewModel QuoteSelectedViewModel { get; set; }
    public QuoteListViewModel QuoteListViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

The QuoteViewModel is :

```
public class QuoteViewModel
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal MonthPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal QuarterPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal BiannualPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal YearPrice { get; set; }

    public List<CoverQuoteViewModel> CoverQuotesViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

The QuoteListViewModel is not relevant here and actually works fine.

Two questions:

1) Why is QuoteSelectedViewModel  mapped as an Object instead of an Observable function ? I understand why it's the case for QuoteListViewModel  because it's an Array, but QuoteSelectedViewModel is not an Array.

2) I can't bind my DOM to QuoteSelectedViewModel. Here's what I do:

```
viewModel.customizeQuote = function () {
  viewModel.QuoteSelectedViewModel = this;
}
```

and customizeQuote is called there:

```
<table data-bind="with: QuoteListViewModel">
 <tbody>
 <tr data-bind="foreach: Quotes">
  <td>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" data-bind="click: $root.customizeQuote">Customize</a>
 </td>
 </tr>
```

When debugging, I can see that QuoteSelectedViewModel contains the correct Quote from the QuoteListViewModel Array. However doing:

```
viewModel.QuoteSelectedViewModel = this;
```

seems incorrect to me. It should be an observable and I should do

```
viewModel.QuoteSelectedViewModel( this );
```

Any idea what's wrong ?

**[EDIT]**

The fact that QuoteSelectedViewModel is not observable is obviously the root of the problem.

I've added the following code:

```
viewModel.SelectedQuote = ko.observable(viewModel.QuoteSelectedViewModel);
```

and in the customize method I do this instead:

```
viewModel.SelectedQuote(this);
```

So now, the list is bound. So how do I make the QuoteSelectedViewModel an observable object right from the beginning when I use the mapping plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping plugin creates observables for the lowest level properties and arrays.  For nested objects it does not make the parent an observable.

```
var test = {
   sub: {
       name: "Bob"
   }
};
```

In this case, it will make `name` an observable, but `sub` will not be observable.

One option is to customize how objects are created using the mapping options, as described [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#customizing_object_construction_using_create).

Comment: thanks, I've updated my original post while you answered my question. I'm going to take a look at your link now.

Comment: @user1098555 If your question is answered that show courtesy and atleast accept the answer

Comment: @JCN, but the question is not answered otherwise I would have marked it as such. See the update to my original post.

Comment: @user1098555 maybe you can get something in jsFiddle?

Comment: well I solved the problem. There's no way around forcing the property QuoteSelectedViewModel to be an observable. So doing so after calling the mapping function did the trick : viewModel.QuoteSelectedViewModel = ko.observable();